# How I can detect when the modules window is open in the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

I'm writing a Delphi plugin and I need detect when the Modules (View - Debug windows - Modules) window is open (attached to IDE Editor). I'm using the  IOTAEditorNotifier to get notified when a new Editor window is open, but only works for source files.

This is the code used to receive the notifications from the IDE Editor.

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, ToolsAPI;

type
  TSourceEditorNotifier = class(TNotifierObject, IOTANotifier, IOTAEditorNotifier)
  private
    FEditor: IOTASourceEditor;
    FIndex: Integer;
    { IOTANotifier }
    procedure Destroyed;
    { IOTAEditorNotifier }
    procedure ViewActivated(const View: IOTAEditView);
    procedure ViewNotification(const View: IOTAEditView; Operation: TOperation);
  public
    constructor Create(AEditor: IOTASourceEditor);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TIDENotifier = class(TNotifierObject, IOTANotifier, IOTAIDENotifier)
  private
    { IOTAIDENotifier }
    procedure FileNotification(NotifyCode: TOTAFileNotification; const FileName: string; var Cancel: Boolean);
    procedure BeforeCompile(const Project: IOTAProject; var Cancel: Boolean); overload;
    procedure AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean); overload;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Dialogs,
  Windows,
  Forms;

var
  SourceEditorNotifiers: TList = nil;
  IDENotifierIndex: Integer = -1;

procedure ClearSourceEditorNotifiers;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(SourceEditorNotifiers) then
    for I := SourceEditorNotifiers.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      TSourceEditorNotifier(SourceEditorNotifiers[I]).Destroyed;
end;

procedure InstallSourceEditorNotifiers(Module: IOTAModule);
var
  I: Integer;
  SourceEditor: IOTASourceEditor;
begin
  for I := 0 to Module.ModuleFileCount - 1 do
    if Supports(Module.ModuleFileEditors[I], IOTAEditor, SourceEditor) then
    begin
      SourceEditorNotifiers.Add(TSourceEditorNotifier.Create(SourceEditor));
      SourceEditor := nil;
    end;
end;

procedure Register;
var
  Services: IOTAServices;
  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  EditorServices: IOTAEditorServices;
  EditorTopView: IOTAEditView;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  SourceEditorNotifiers := TList.Create;

  // install IDE notifier so that we can install editor notifiers for any newly opened module
  Services := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAServices;
  IDENotifierIndex := Services.AddNotifier(TIDENotifier.Create);

  // install editor notifiers for all currently open modules
  ModuleServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices;
  if ModuleServices.ModuleCount = 0 then
    Exit;
  for I := 0 to ModuleServices.ModuleCount - 1 do
    InstallSourceEditorNotifiers(ModuleServices.Modules[I]);

  // hook currently active module
  EditorServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAEditorServices;
  if not Assigned(EditorServices) then
    Exit;

  EditorTopView := EditorServices.TopView;
  if not Assigned(EditorTopView) then
    Exit;

  for I := 0 to SourceEditorNotifiers.Count - 1 do
    with TSourceEditorNotifier(SourceEditorNotifiers[I]) do
      for J := 0 to FEditor.EditViewCount - 1 do
        if FEditor.EditViews[J] = EditorTopView then
        begin
          ViewActivated(EditorTopView);
          Exit;
        end;
end;


procedure RemoveIDENotifier;
var
  Services: IOTAServices;
begin
  Services := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAServices;
  if Assigned(Services) then
    Services.RemoveNotifier(IDENotifierIndex);
end;

procedure TSourceEditorNotifier.Destroyed;
begin
  FEditor.RemoveNotifier(FIndex);
end;

procedure TSourceEditorNotifier.ViewActivated(const View: IOTAEditView);
begin
  // Do nothing
end;

procedure TSourceEditorNotifier.ViewNotification(const View: IOTAEditView; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  if Operation=opInsert then
  ShowMessage('ViewNotification opInsert');
end;

constructor TSourceEditorNotifier.Create(AEditor: IOTASourceEditor);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FEditor := AEditor;
  FIndex := FEditor.AddNotifier(Self);
end;

destructor TSourceEditorNotifier.Destroy;
begin
  SourceEditorNotifiers.Remove(Self);
  FEditor := nil;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TIDENotifier.AfterCompile(Succeeded: Boolean);
begin
  // do nothing
end;

procedure TIDENotifier.BeforeCompile(const Project: IOTAProject; var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  // do nothing
end;

procedure TIDENotifier.FileNotification(NotifyCode: TOTAFileNotification; const FileName: string; var Cancel: Boolean);
var
  ModuleServices: IOTAModuleServices;
  Module: IOTAModule;
begin
  case NotifyCode of
    ofnFileOpened:
      begin
        ModuleServices := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAModuleServices;
        Module := ModuleServices.FindModule(FileName);
        if Assigned(Module) then
          InstallSourceEditorNotifiers(Module);
      end;
  end;
end;

initialization

finalization
  RemoveIDENotifier;
  ClearSourceEditorNotifiers;
  FreeAndNil(SourceEditorNotifiers);


end.
```

How I can detect the modules window is open in the Delphi IDE Editor?

Comment: I think you adopted totally wrong code. `Modules` is OTA terms have nothing to do with process modules in common sense Win32 debugging terms. There is not OTA services for that, you should go to VCL level and look for appropriate **form**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the ToolsAPI doesn't provide any notifier for such situation. But you can try intercepting the windows activation using a  [`WH_CBT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_cbthook)  hook, try the [`HCBT_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `HCBT_SETFOCUS` codes. For a Delphi sample check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575699/delphi-detect-when-a-new-form-has-been-created).