# Delphi Expert: How to register IOTAEditorNotifier callback

Tags: delphi, toolsapi, opentools, otapi

I am writing a Delphi IDE expert (OpenToolsAPI). I want to receive callbacks for the IOTAEditorNotifier interface.

```
  IOTAEditorNotifier = interface(IOTANotifier)
    ['{0E3B9D7B-E119-11D1-AB0C-00C04FB16FB3}']
    { Called when a new edit view is created(opInsert) or destroyed(opRemove) }
    procedure ViewNotification(const View: IOTAEditView; Operation: TOperation);
    { Called when a view is activated }
    procedure ViewActivated(const View: IOTAEditView);
  end;
```

How do I register to get those events? I don't find an AddNotifier call that accepts the IOTAEditorNotifier interface.

Comment: Your answer is in the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499166/how-i-can-detect-when-the-modules-window-is-open-in-the-delphi-ide). IOTAServices.AddNotifier.

Comment: You could use this as a reference: http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/?p=1272