# What external events trigger TCustomForm.RecreateWnd?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

A particular VCL application is crashing, rarely, and apparently spontaneously, and I strongly suspect it is because the main form's window handle is being recreated in response to some external trigger from the operating system.

I do know for certain that *if* the main form's window handle were to change then trouble would certainly follow (because background threads post messages to this handle).

But I would like to know how to reproduce this bug before I set about making code changes intended to fix it, if only so I can confirm that this is a plausible cause of the crashes, that the symptoms match those reported, and that the code changes do indeed fix it. (Also if there is no way the OS can trigger a call to `TCustomForm.RecreateWnd` I need to find some other explanation for the crashes. Yes, I could post `CM_RECREATEWND` to the main form but that just begs the question.)

(I am aware that the correct way to post messages from background threads to the VCL thread is to create a hidden message window purely for this purpose using `AllocateHWnd` - that is my proposed fix.)

I have seen a similar error with a descendent of `TCustomListView` where `RecreateWnd` was being triggered by changing the desktop style from *Windows XP* to *Windows Classic*. But I haven't been able yet to find such a method to trigger `RecreateWnd` on a `TCustomForm`. (I've spent a considerable amount of time reading through the VCL code and I must be missing something.)

**Summary:**

Under what stimuli from the operating system does the VCL end up calling `RecreateWnd` on a `TCustomForm`? (I'm especially interested in Windows 7 if that makes a difference.)

If there is such a stimulus from the OS, I can prove whether it causes the observed symptoms. If there definitively isn't then I can prove window recreation isn't the cause.

Comment: I can't back it up, but I've seen the window handle change every time another VCL style is applied.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the vcl. That's where I would start

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've already spent the entire morning reading the VCL source and either I'm missing something, or the OS doesn't trigger RecreateWnd on forms. I was hoping someone might just know the answer.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful `TStyleManager.SetStyle` sends `CM_CUSTOMSTYLECHANGED` to each form, which the triggers `CM_RECREATEWND`, but this doesn't seem to occur in response to an OS event. (At least changing the Windows 7 theme doesn't trigger it.) I presume it happens when you apply a different skin programatically.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that window recreation is the problem? You've got a madexcept log or similar I presume?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Only indirect evidence I'm afraid. There are a number of different symptoms but the most common ones are the GUI 'spontaneously' stops receiving updates (from the worker threads) - so no MadExcept log for that, and a crash involving TCustomListView that appears somewhat like the one I mentioned in the question. I've never seen the problem first hand though.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to be 100% sure that you've found the specific recreation trigger anyway. You may as well just get your app to recreate the window in response to some external trigger. And then see if you get behaviour consistent with what your clients report. You need to fix the bug no matter what though. I'd probably just fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I'll do that. But I'm assuming that any external trigger that causes RecreateWnd will have the same effect. So I don't care whether I find the specific trigger, but I do very much care whether there is (a non-artificial) one. **If there isn't**, then I might have fixed a bug but won't have fixed the problem the users are reporting :-(

Comment: Override CreateWindowHandle and make a log, and for app startup and exit. Then you don't have to guess if the window is recreated. This is assuming it's the main form, need to adjust otherwise.

Comment: Why would your app **crash** even if `RecreateWnd` was triggered if all you do is post messages from a worker threads?

Comment: @kobik One possible reason is that component properties that aren't published don't automatically get preserved across RecreateWnd. So for instance a reference could become invalid. I think I've got more than one different fault, and I want to find out if RecreateWnd could be a common trigger. Knowing this will let me either reproduce the faults at will or rule this out as a possible cause. When you can't reproduce the problem, debugging is HARD.

Comment: See [How do I make form or windowed control RecreateWnd-aware properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21011780/576719).

Answer (score 1):

Windows will destroy your form if it is owned or parented to another window that is being destroyed.

That will cause your form's handle to be destroyed.

But since your form is still around, Delphi will re-create the handle the next time.

Comment: Good point. This mechanism wouldn't be explicit as such in the VCL source. What if the owner form was the Delphi application object? I'm guessing that *doesn't* get destroyed and recreated during the normal lifetime of the process.

Comment: @IanGoldby That is true. Windows never (is unable) to call `RecreateWnd`. That method is called internally when the window handle needs to be recreated. The VCL source code is littered with the situations when a form's handle will need to be re-created (e.g. you change the `FormStyle`, `BorderStyle`, `BiDiMode`, `BorderIcons`, `Position`. But in all these cases, it is the VCL itself doing it.

Comment: The crucial point is that it is the VCL doing it *in response to something in the developer's application code* rather than in response to something that happens externally (such as the user changing the desktop style).

Comment: Things like docking/undocking, re-parenting, window style changes, VCL style changes, etc will all trigger window re-creations. Also, any external destruction of a window will reset the owning control's `Handle` to 0 and destroy all child windows, resetting child control `Handle`s to 0 as well.