# Let form catch all messages

Tags: delphi, windows-messages

I am in a situation where I would like to have a form in my application catch all the custom messages i post from other forms. The messages may be send with a handle that is not the handle of the 'sniffer'
Is that possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch certain events of a form from outside the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743876/how-do-i-catch-certain-events-of-a-form-from-outside-the-form)

Comment: You want to sniff all messages that are posted with `PostMessage`? You don't want to sniff synchronous messages send with `SendMessage`? If so handle `TApplication.OnMessage`.

Comment: Working like I want - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Drop a TApplicationEvents component on the form and handle the OnMessage Event